# Изменить событие нажатия клавиш

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть отличная штука http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gqbex

Там есть такие события — enter - submit, shift-enter - newline (перевод строки).

Мне нужно изменить клавишу shift на ctrl. Казалось бы меняй, в чем проблема?
Проблема есть.

Меняю — не работает.

Вот смотрите http://codepen.io/anon/pen/byEmc

Comment: У меня ваш второй пример работает с клавишей Ctrl.

Comment: @LinnTroll, второй пример по ctrl + enter переводит строку и по enter отправляет?

Какой у вас браузер?

Comment: Именно так. Браузер - хром 37.0.2062.122

Попробовал firefox - не работает перевод строки.

Comment: @LinnTroll, У меня Версия 37.0.2062.120 m

Так как быть?